# Inserting an image using pysimplegui python

Tags: python, image, user-interface, jpeg, pysimplegui

I wish to load the image saved in file 'D:\Users\j84202301\Desktop\dog.jpg' to my GUI interface in python. How can I do so without the user having to press a button? So far I managed to implement the code found below, but I wish that the image is loaded immediately when the program is run and not after a button is pressed. Can someone help me out please?

```
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

layout = [[sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
          [sg.Button("Load Image")]
          ]
window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Load Image":
        image = Image.open(r'D:\Users\j84202301\Desktop\dog.jpg')
        image.thumbnail((200, 200))
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(bio, format="PNG")
        window["-IMAGE-"].update(data=bio.getvalue())
window.close()
```

Comment: Using option `data` of Image element, like `sg.Image(data=bio.getvalue(), key="-IMAGE-")`

Comment: I did not understand what you said @JasonYang

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it update the image with the data converted from your JPEG file when button `'Load Image'` clicked.

To load this JPEG file immediately when the program start, just set option `data` when Image element initiated.

```py
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r'D:\Users\j84202301\Desktop\dog.jpg')
image.thumbnail((200, 200))
bio = io.BytesIO()
image.save(bio, format="PNG")

layout = [[sg.Image(data=bio.getvalue(), key="-IMAGE-")],
          [sg.Button("Load Image")]
          ]
window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Or update the Image element after window finalized.

```py
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r'D:\Users\j84202301\Desktop\dog.jpg')
image.thumbnail((200, 200))
bio = io.BytesIO()
image.save(bio, format="PNG")

layout = [[sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
          [sg.Button("Load Image")]
          ]
window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout, finalize=True)
window["-IMAGE-"].update(data=bio.getvalue())

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Or using Graph element, then you can draw image at any location where to place image's top left corner, when window finalized.

```py
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r'D:\Users\j84202301\Desktop\dog.jpg')
image.thumbnail((200, 200))
bio = io.BytesIO()
image.save(bio, format="PNG")

w, h = (640, 480)
layout = [[sg.Graph((w, h), (0, h), (w, 0), key="-GRAPH-")],
          [sg.Button("Load Image")]
          ]
window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout, finalize=True)
window["-GRAPH-"].draw_image(data=bio.getvalue(), location=(50, 100))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I will use the first one! Thanks so much!

Comment: By any chance, do you know how I can select the position of where the image is placed please?

Comment: Basically, Image element is filled up by the image, so you cannot select the position of where the image is placed. Try Graph element, update as above.